# Do I need to do compute stats after insert overwrite in impala

Tags: impala

Suppose I have done `create table` and `compute stats` before, I do it behind.

```
create table xxx;
insert table xxx;
compute stats xxx;
```

And I can use `describe formatted` this table to find something useful.